# Let $(K,\le)$ an extension ordered field of $(\Bbb Q,\le)$. Prove that $K$ is archimedean if $\forall a\in K_{>0},\exists q\in\Bbb Q: 0<q<a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $(K,\le)$ an extension ordered field of $(\Bbb Q,\le)$. Prove that $K$ is archimedean if $\forall a\in K_{>0},\exists q\in\Bbb Q: 0<q<a$.

Im "almost sure" that my proof is correct but I want a validation. Check my proof please, thank you in advance.

> A field $K$ is archimedean if for any $a,b\in K_{\ge 0}$ and $a>0$ exists some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $na>b$.

**First part:** let $a\in K_{>0}$, then exists $q$ such that $0<q<a$. Then using axioms of ordered fields I get

$$0<q<a\iff 0<nq<na\iff 0<nqa^{-1}<n\quad(\forall n\in\Bbb N_{>0})$$

then from the property of $K$ we have again that

$$0<p<nqa^{-1}\iff 0<pa<nq\iff 0<a<p^{-1}nq$$

where $p^{-1}nq\in\Bbb Q_{>0}$ and due to the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is archimedean then exists some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $p^{-1}nq<mq$. Then cause $mq\in\Bbb Q$ what is archimedean exists some $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $mq<k$ and then we have

$$0<a<mq\implies 0<q<a<mq<k\tag{1}$$

---

EDIT: second try... thank you for commenting @Arthur... this kind of silly mistakes is the reason for the verification for these simple proofs.

**Second part**: let WLOG $b>a>0$ with $a,b\in K$. Then, by the first part we know that

$$(0<q<a<mq)\land (0<p<b<np)\implies 0<a<b<np$$

for some $n,m\in\Bbb N$ and some $p,q\in\Bbb Q$.

We can write $np=aa^{-1}np$ and then by $(1)$ we have that  $a^{-1}np<k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, then $b<ak$, and the proof is over.

Comment: But Archimedean is a property concerning two arbitrary elements $a,b\in K_{\geq0}$. Where did $b$ go?

Comment: @Arthur I taken $q$ as $b$... maybe it is not right because is not a general element of $K$. I didnt see, thank you.

Comment: If $K$ is an extension of $Q$, then $K$ contains $Q$, so there can't possibly be $q$ in $Q$ with $0<q<a$ for all $a$ in $K$.